# With Supertest, can I create an alternative request with some headers set by default?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, supertest

I am using [Supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) with Mocha to test an API developed with Node JS.

And I want to do a lót of different tests on the API. With almost all of them I have to set Authorization and Content-Type headers again (because the API requires them for this test).

```
it('Creation without an email address should fail and return error code 50040', function(done) {
  request
    .post('/mpl/entities')
    .set('Authorization', 'Token 1234567890') //set header for this test
    .set('Content-Type',  'application/json') //set header for this test
    .send({
      firstname: "test"
    })
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
    .expect(500)
    .expect(anErrorCode('50040'))
    .end(done);
});

it('Creation with a duplicate email address should fail and return error code 50086', function(done) {
  request
    .post('/mpl/entities')
    .set('Authorization', 'Token 1234567890') //<-- again
    .set('Content-Type',  'application/json') //<-- again, I'm getting tired
    .send({
      email: "a@b.nl"
    })
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
    .expect(500)
    .expect(anErrorCode('50086'))
    .end(done);
});
```

Can I create an alternative request with those headers set by default?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If i remember correctly in superagent one can pass a hash to set

```
agent.set({key:value,key2:value2})
```

let me know if it doesnt work with supertest.

Comment: Just tried it and it works with Supertest. Thanks. Now I have an object stored somewhere `var base = {'Authorization': 'Token 1234567890', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'};` and with every new test I do `.set(base)`. This saves me redundant lines of code. Thanks. Hope to find an answer to setting default headers and save me even more lines. Update: Actually, this is just good enough. Accepted your answer.

Comment: This works for superagent, but not for supertest, e.g. `supertest(app).set(...)` does not work. Is there a way to access the agent behind supertest to call `.set()` on it?

Answer (score 23):

You could use a common routine to build your "default" headers as an object and pass them to the request:

```
//# file:config.js

var config = { 
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:8080",
  authorization: { "Authorization":"authvalue" }
}

// Content-Type left out because supertest will use Content-Type json when you use the appropriate method

module.exports = config;
```

And now in your test.js:

```
//# file:test.js

var request = require("supertest");
var config = require("./config");

request = request(config.baseUrl+"/api/getTokenValue")
//code to get token value from request

var commonHeaders = { 
  "authorization":tokenValue,
  "X-Testing-Value":1,
  "X-Common-Header":"value"
};

describe("testing", function() {
  it.should('present authorization header to server', function(done) {
    request.get('/someurl')
      .set(commonHeaders)
      .set({"X-TestSpecificHeader":"Value"})
      .expect(200,done) //if not authorized you'd get 401
  });
  it.should('do something else', function(done) {
    request.get('/someUrl')
      .set(commonHeaders)
      .expect(200,done)
  });
})
```

Also, if you need to have your app get that token value at runtime (most likely) see this article for using a requested token value that is generated for the tests:
https://jaketrent.com/post/authenticated-supertest-tests/

Answer (score 8):

You can use the library [`superagent-defaults`](https://github.com/camshaft/superagent-defaults) as follows:

### installation

```sh
npm install --save-dev supertest superagent-defaults
```

### usage

```js
var defaults = require('superagent-defaults');
var supertest = require('supertest');

var request = defaults(supertest(app)); // or url

// set the default headers
request.set(commonHeaders);

// use as usually
```

### version

- supertest v3.0.0
- superagent-defaults v0.1.14

Answer (score 2):

What I use to do is something like

First I create a config file to store the default Headers,

Config File:

```
//# file: defaults.js
var defaults = { 
  l5dDtab: "SomeValue",
  xSignature: true,
  ... more headers here
}
module.exports = defaults;
```

Then, on each test file where I use supertest I do this:

```
var defaults = require('./defaults.js');
var supertest = require('supertest');

var host = 'http://localhost:8080';
var request = supertest.agent(host)
            .set("l5d-dtab", defaults.l5dDtab)
            .set("X-Signature", defaults.xSignature);
var response = request.get("SomePath").set("AnotherLocalHeader", "Value");
```